# Commandline tool to set msspecific "rating" tag in jpeg

Tags: batch-file, exiftool

I want to create a windows batchfile to set tags of jpeg-files to the contents of a database.
i am using ExifTool-6.93 for this. this works perfect setting "keywords".
Unfortunatly exiftool cannot write the ms-windows specific "rating" tag.

this works perfectly (read keywords and rating, write keywords)

```
ExifTool.exe -keywords -rating test.jpg
ExifTool.exe -keywords=testTag test.jpg
```

this does not work because ExifTool cannot write rating

```
ExifTool.exe -rating=2 test.jpg
```

do you know any ms commandline tool that can set the rating-tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of ExifTool will write this tag.  The version you are using is 6 years old.

Comment: ups i downloaded the new version but through the path executed the old one. :-(