# How to change "comments" on files in windows from command line?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, filesystems, properties

In windows on certain files users are able to change the "comments" on the file. This can be done by right clicking the file -> properties -> Details as shown in this [image](http://res2.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%20vista/main/d82eb014-63a1-418b-b12f-b58beb8909b8_14.png)

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to do this from the command line?
2. Is there a way to do this programmatically in a non-windows environment? Meaning, can the comments be added to a file in a non-windows box and when that file is moved to a windows box then those comments are actually visible?

Comment: I think those are "tags and ratings". http://superuser.com/questions/605970/commandline-tool-to-set-msspecific-rating-tag-in-jpeg  http://superuser.com/questions/119496/modifying-value-of-rating-column-within-explorer-for-arbitrary-file-types  they are lost (or removed) when moving to FAT file systems.

Comment: did you mean that its lost when moved from FAT file system? windows is a FAT file system and I've moved a file with comments around different windows systems and am able to read the comments in both boxes.

Comment: I do not know.  if its is actually in the file as some EXIF data is, there is no reason to believe that moving the whole of that file anywhere would change the data internal to it.  Just that it has been Mentioned many times that at least some aspects of windows "tags and ratings" have been tossed, when moved to other file systems.